# JS parsing a text file line by line

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have a file [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OefAb.png)

How can I parse this file line by line with JS and put 1 line in 1 HTML element?

```js
function loadTxt() {
    jQuery.get('http://localhost:8000/np/nowPlaying.txt', function(data) {
        var nowPlaying = data;
        
//        what do I do there?
        
        document.getElementById('track').innerHTML = track;
//        ...
    });
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadtTxt();">
  <p>Now playing</p>
  <span id="track"></span>
  <span id="by"></span>
  <span id="artist"></span>
  <span id="from"></span>
  <span id="album"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Starting point: [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `data` variable is your files contents as a string, you can split it based on `\n` for new line. In your function, do this:

```
    var splitted = data.split("\n");
    var i = 0;
    document.querySelector("#track").innerHTML = splitted[i++];
    document.querySelector("#by").innerHTML = splitted[i++];
    document.querySelector("#artist").innerHTML = splitted[i++];
    document.querySelector("#from").innerHTML = splitted[i++];
    document.querySelector("#album").innerHTML = splitted[i];
```